# Backend menu administrator GUI broke

Tags: administrator, menu, fatal-error

When trying to edit or add menu item in Menu Manager, I have lost the GUI interface and all of the functionality.

Just updated to Joomla! 3.4.4 Stable [ Ember ] 8-September-2015 21:30 GMT 
and noticed the problem after the upgrade.

Any thoughts? I'm running RocketTheme Gantry framework on the site and have no trouble before the upgrade.

[image: Screenshot illustrating problem]

Comment: Have you tried different admin templates? Purge cache, history, different browser etc? Is it effecting all menu functionality?

Comment: Tried all the usual stuff, but fixed by identifying the errant plug-in/template that was causing problem. Found it by turning on Debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot you posted make me think that there must be a **Fatal Error** somewhere. Enable `error_reporting` to see if any exists and where it comes from.

Most likely it will be an outdated extension, and by updating or uninstalling/removing it, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: You were right - error was in an unused plugin installed by a site template I rejected.  Fixed now!

Comment: @GrannyKat please consider to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem